# Apache phpinfo missing cURL and XDebug after upgrade

Tags: php, curl, xdebug

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and went to check on my local apache2 installation by adding phpinfo() to an index file.

After update/reboot, I went to my local WordPress Admin area and attenpted to update a plugin and got the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_init()
```

Here's what I did:

1. I checked phpinfo() and no curl OR xdebug options are shown.
2. I went to /etc/php/7.1/apache2/php.ini and uncommented the following line extension=php_curl.dll.
3. I then restarted apache.
4. Also, my phpinfo() shows Loaded Configuration File
   /etc/php/7.1/apache2/php.ini and THAT is the one I've been editing.

However, WordPress still reports the following: PHP Fatal error: 
Call to undefined function curl_init().

I'm thinking I MUST be editing the wrong ini file.

Any ideas? I'm dead in the water here.

Comment: Do you `uncomment` to get curl running on Ubuntu I usually see this on window systems?

Comment: When I upgraded my server from 16 to 18, including ondrej's apache ppa, there was some conflict that ended up with libcurl3 getting uninstalled to resolve. So I had to reinstall curl and then it was OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had the same problem as you, but with nextcloud.
Sadly I didn't wrote down, what worked. I looked up in m histfile.

Try some of these and tell me what worked:

```
apt install php-curl
a2dismod php7.0
a2enmod php7.2
```

If it still doesnt work I could use this Information:

```
ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php*
```

EDIT

[sleeper](https://askubuntu.com/users/417700) found a solution for php7.1 . You need to know your php version you want. Then you can install php7.1-curl (or your version of your php).

[Source: unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/460697/php-missing-curl-and-xdebug-after-upgrade/460705#460705)

Comment: Here is the output of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php* - /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.1.conf  /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.1.load

Comment: Perhaps switching to php7.2 might help

Comment: I did that and phpinfo IS showing curl and xdebug. Yay! BUT... now I cannot login to wordpress (locally) at all. White screen of death. Non-WP site appears to be fine.

Comment: OK, so switching to php7.2 hosed up WordPress (for some reason) so I went back to 7.1 (which brought back local WP installations), then I ran the following: apt-get install php7.1-curl and that brought back curl! So I guess I'm good to go.  In fairness, this question was posted on unix.stackexchange.com first, (because, in my panic, I simply forgot about this group for  a moment) and Rui F Ribeiro provided a working solution. Ref: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/460705/89702 ...so maybe this thread is likely a duplicate and can/should be deleted(?)

Comment: I'm glad you you finally found someting. I dont know neither, if we should delete it or mark as duplicate. I will correct our solution, so everyone who is looking for a similar question can find faster your solution. If somebody want to delet it, he can.